# better approach to load referential data

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have entities related to cities in my Neo4j graph. I've created a form in which a user can create an entity, let's say a shop. In this form, I would like the user to choose the city of the shop from a combo box. I'm wondering what is the best approach : get all the cities from the graph with a cypher query or have all the cities (and other referential data) in another database (relational or nosql or whatever), and then populate my comboboxes  ? Or is there a better approach ?

Thanks for your time,

Didier

Answer (score 0):

I've just heard of polyglot persistence and read some articles. Should it be, in my case, the best approach to store cities and shops in a document database and then use my graph database to add relationships with customers, shops and cities?